# Should you deploy django with wsgi?

Tags: python, django, networking, server, wsgi

Do you need to deploy django with wsgi? I am running Django on a Docker instance and it seems like often the recommended solution is just to use Django's development server, i.e. the command `python manage.py runserver`. When exactly is a web server such as wsgi needed -- and in this instance, in a containerized application, is the django development server enough for production applications?

Comment: Who is recommending you to use Django's development server (sqlite)?

Comment: For example, this repository uses the development server to run Django: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/docker-django-webapp-linux

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You answer your own question:

> is the django **development** server enough for **production** applications ?

In the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial01/#the-development-server), you can read the following:

> Now’s a good time to note: don’t use this server in anything resembling a production environment. It’s intended only for use while developing. (We’re in the business of making Web frameworks, not Web servers.)

And also [this part](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#runserver):

> **DO NOT USE THIS SERVER IN A PRODUCTION SETTING**. It has not gone through **security** audits or **performance** tests. (And that’s how it’s gonna stay. We’re in the business of making Web frameworks, not Web servers, so improving this server to be able to handle a production environment is outside the scope of Django.)

So no. Don't use the Django development server in production. Security risks, poor performances, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The development server is never recommended as an option for production server. It has a number of [security and performance issues](http://DO%20NOT%20USE%20THIS%20SERVER%20IN%20A%20PRODUCTION%20SETTING.%20It%20has%20not%20gone%20through%20security%20audits%20or%20performance%20tests.%20(And%20that%E2%80%99s%20how%20it%E2%80%99s%20gonna%20stay.%20We%E2%80%99re%20in%20the%20business%20of%20making%20Web%20frameworks,%20not%20Web%20servers,%20so%20improving%20this%20server%20to%20be%20able%20to%20handle%20a%20production%20environment%20is%20outside%20the%20scope%20of%20Django.)).

The solution which is working well for us is Gunicorn behind an Nginx reverse proxy (so that multiple people can connect smoothly.)

The method mentioned in [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04) is a good beginners guide to a Ubuntu setup with nginx and gunicorn. When bringing docker into the mix use [this tutorial.](http://ruddra.com/2016/08/14/docker-django-nginx-postgres/)

Answer (score -2):

You can use [Django Channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deploying.html) to deploy in production without using WSGI.

> You can set things up in one of two ways; either route all traffic through a HTTP/WebSocket interface server, removing the need to run a WSGI server at all; or, just route WebSockets and long-poll HTTP connections to the interface server, and leave other pages served by a standard WSGI server.